# how to store all windows configure of a tmux session into a file

Tags: tmux

Supposing now I have a tmux sesiion with seven windows. I have already configured them with a good name, such as,

window 1 with title "homedir",

window 2 with title "work",

window 3 with title "play", ...

Now I have another computer, and I what to keep all my configures above, and send it to that new computer. So what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many tools can achieve that. I wrote a script to do tmux (window/session/pane...) "backup & restore" too, you can give it a try:

https://github.com/sk1418/retmux